# WordPress get current post id of custom post type in functions.php function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function in my functions.php file and I need the current post ID.

I have tried getting it like this:

```
global $wp_query;
$currentID = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($currentID);
echo '</pre>';
```

but doesn't seem to work since it says:

> Trying to get property of non-object

**EDIT: Entire function in functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_1', 'populate_posts' );
function populate_posts( $form ) {
    global $wp_query;

    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

        if ( $field->type != 'select' || strpos($field['cssClass'], 'booking-option') === false ) {
            continue;
        }


        $currentID = $wp_query->post->ID;
        var_dump($wp_query->post);

        $choices[] = array( 'text' => $price, 'value' => $price );


        $field->placeholder = '0';
        $field->choices = $choices;

    }

    return $form;
}
```

Anyone can help me out please

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What output do you have if you give a var_dump of $wp_query->post ? Please update your question with that output.

Comment: @Anonymous I get nothing to see, it's like wordpress ignores my function for some reason... I'll update OP

Comment: Ok. Where do you call your function?

Comment: @Anonymous checkout OP I updated it

Comment: First of, you have an "&" in your foreach loop, just before the $field, that should not be there. Second of all your need to get your posts something like this  $posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1&post_status=publish' ); and then use another foreach loop in the main loop to get the id of the post. I think.

Comment: [`$wp_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Misc) (object) is the global instance of the `WP_Query` class. If it's not object in your case, you must have it overriden somewhere. Call [`wp_reset_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) after querying posts to restore $wp_query and global post data to the original main query.

Comment: @Anonymous I used this code from this example in the gravity forms documentation https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/dynamically-populating-drop-down-fields/

Comment: Ok. And there is a second foreach loop that you are missing in your code.

Comment: @Anonymous no because I don't want to loop over all my posts. I just need data about the posts I am currently on. That's why I need the post ID

Comment: Then make your query to loop over the posts you want. What's that hard?! Change your query arguments to get only the posts you want. Or get all the posts and then in your foreach loop take the id's from the posts you want. That simple.

Comment: @Anonymous The thing that doesn't want to work is that no matter what I do inside my function nothing seems to work. Even if I just do and echo 'hello'

Comment: Then check your if statement. Maybe there's your problem. I can't debug your code from just seeing it from here. It seems fine but there is a problem somewhere. Try getting it step by step. and see where your problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

In your function add

```
 global $post;
 echo $post->ID;
```

Comment: This also gives `Trying to get property of non-object` error

Answer (score 0):

To have access to the post id you must be within [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Otherwise , you must modify your function to accept the post id as a parameter , and hook where is safe to get post id, like so:

```
add_action('template_redirect', function() {
  if (is_single())
    your_function(get_queried_object_id());
  }
});

function your_function($id){
    //Do what you want
}
```

Some references:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177262/cant-get-post-id-in-functions-php?rq=1
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140753/get-current-post-id-in-functions-php

As a note, for the future i think is more appropriate if you post these questions to the http://wordpress.stackexchange.com community

**EDIT:**

now that you posted the entire code i see that you are using gravity forms (which you didn't mentioned before).

This is a completely different question then.
You must obtain the post_id from the Entry object that gravity forms will pass to your function

https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/entry-object/

Comment: This gives me a lot of errors and where exactly does the id get stored in the $id ?

Comment: The get_queried_object_id() function call says:    

Retrieve ID of the current queried object.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/

Comment: This is get passed to your_function as an argument then

Comment: See the updated answer, you wasn't clear. Now that you posted the full source is easier to help you.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to print the ID then use

the_ID();

if you want to store it then use

$postId = get_the_ID();

Use it in the loop

Hope this helps

Take Care and Happy coding

Comment: I am not using the loop... That's the whole point of my question :D If I was using the loop then there was no problem :)

Comment: you can store the post_id's in an array while the loop is running and then you can use that variable array in the function by calling it with global keyword

Answer (score -1):

**Getting the current post ID**

**The ID can be stored as a variable using**

```
<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?>
```

**To print**

```
<?php echo $postid; ?>
```

**By function**

```
 function get_the_ID() {
   $post = get_post();
   return ! empty( $post ) ? $post->ID : false;
 }
```

**For Reference :** [click here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/)